# Java looping two-dimensional array with if conditions

Tags: java, arrays, loops, if-statement

I'm trying to do a certain project and there is this part in which I want to loop in a two-dimensional (2D) array and if the certain value of `i` and `j` then do something.

To be more specific my 2D array is defined for files and users (the attached photo might explain well); I want, for example, when `i = 0` and `j = 0` equals `1` then print out that user `1` can write in file. I was able to iterate over the array and find the indexes where `1`'s occur in the array with the following code:

[my 2d array defined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yT2XE.jpg)

```
public class Test {
  public int counteri = 0;
  public int counterj = 0;

  public void readpermission(int[][] array) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
        if (array[i][j] == 1) {
          counterj = j;
          counteri = i;
          System.out.println("found 1's at index =" + counteri + " " + counterj);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

found 1's at index =0 0,

found 1's at index =0 1

found 1's at index =0 4

found 1's at index =1 1

found 1's at index =1 2

found 1's at index =1 3

found 1's at index =1 4

found 1's at index =1 5
```

When the first value is `0 0`, I want an output that user `1` can write in file `1` and when the output is `0 1` I want an output stating that user `1` can read in file 1...and so on.

Comment: Hint: you expect us to spend our time to help you. So you please spend the 1 minute it takes to properly format/indent your source code. And then sorry, your question is not at all clear. Please give a short example, for example on exact input data. And tell us where your problem is. You are already iterating that two-dim array, and you are checking for a condition while doing that. So what exactly is it that you have problems with?

Comment: @GhostCat:  i guess my source code is formatted in a proper way and i do find it hard to explain my problem and i do appreciate your time helping me thats why im using stackoverflow, my example was mentioned above lets talk about the problem it self now in my 2d array when i=0 and j=0 there is a 1 in my array i want an if condition for example if(array[i=0][j=0]==1) { system.out.println("user 1 can read in file 1)

Comment: Your source code contains 5 to 10 empty lines that add no value whatsoever. Anything that doesn't add value to code reduces its readability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your last comment:

```
if(array[i=0][j=0]==1)
```

could be

```
if (i==0 && j==0 && array[i][j] == 1)
```

But the point is: that is really basic java syntax; and you should not need to come here and ask about that. Instead: you study tutorials and education materials that tells you how to do work with java syntax, for example [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html).

But please note: the whole thing that you are describing doesn't make too much sense. You are using *int* values to *model* permissions. That is not a good idea. Instead: you could create your own Permission class; or at least: use an [enum](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) instead of int values. Assuming that an int with value 1 ... means "write access" is simply a very naive and actually not-at-all intuitive model.

Comment: Thankyou for the answer and i know its really simplebut i do deliberate it this way! thanks for wasting your time!!